# Fastify Schema Issue schema is invalid: data.properties should be object

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, fastify

I am developing a service to generate schema from my interfaces in `typescript`

Here is the

> schema generated a part of, I have omitted other parts for sake of simplicity and readability

```json
{
    "$id": "auth",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "IUserRegisterRequestBody": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "examples": [{
                "attributes": {
                    "organization": "crowdtsaffing",
                    "subdomain": "app",
                    "user_id": "79f6f9c5-3ee3-4ddf-b859-c18d3e56fe14",
                    "user_type": "internal"
                },
                "email": "merajs@gmail.com",
                "first_name": "Meraj Ahmad",
                "last_name": "Siddiqui",
                "password": "abcd",
                "username": "merajs"
            }],
            "properties": {
                "attributes": {
                    "$ref": "auth#/definitions/IUserAttribute",
                    "description": "User Attributes",
                    "title": "attributes"
                },
                "email": {
                    "description": "Unique Email of the user",
                    "title": "email",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "first_name": {
                    "description": "First Name of the User",
                    "title": "first_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "description": "Last Name of User",
                    "title": "last_name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "password": {
                    "description": "Encrypted password of the User",
                    "title": "password",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "username": {
                    "description": "Service Generated or Chosen username",
                    "title": "username",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "attributes",
                "email",
                "first_name",
                "last_name",
                "password",
                "username"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        },
        "IErrorResponse": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "message": {
                    "description": "Generated Error message",
                    "title": "message",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "message"
            ],
            "title": "IErrorResponse",
            "type": "object"
        },
        "IUserResponse": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "200": {
                    "additionalProperties": true,
                    "properties": {},
                    "title": "200",
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "401": {
                    "$ref": "auth#/definitions/IErrorResponse",
                    "description": "UnAuthorized Request",
                    "title": "401"
                },
                "403": {
                    "$ref": "auth#/definitions/IErrorResponse",
                    "description": "Permission Denies",
                    "title": "403"
                },
                "404": {
                    "$ref": "auth#/definitions/IErrorResponse",
                    "description": "Resource not found",
                    "title": "404"
                },
                "500": {
                    "$ref": "auth#/definitions/IErrorResponse",
                    "description": "Internal Server Error",
                    "title": "500"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "200",
                "401",
                "403",
                "404",
                "500"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am adding the schema to fastify app instance

```js
import * as JSONSchema from "./schemas/schemas.json";
import {UserRoutesProvider} from './routes/user.route';
import {ClientRoutesProvider} from "./routes/client.route";
import {SwaggerDocumentationOptions} from './swagger';

export class App {
    /**
     * @var app FastifyInstance
     */
    public app: FastifyInstance;

    constructor() {
        this.app = Fastify.default({logger: {level: process.env.LOG}});
        this.app.register(FastifySwaggerPlugin, SwaggerDocumentationOptions);
        this.app.addSchema(JSONSchema);
        this.enableErrorHandler();
        this.app.register(fastifyCors, {origin: '*'});
        this.enableRoutes();
    }
```

Please not the line `this.app.addSchema(JSONSchema);` in constructor
After that i define my schema and routes like

```js
export const UserRegisterRequest = {
    header: {$ref: 'auth#/definitions/IClientCredential'},
    body: {$ref: 'auth#/definitions/IUserRegisterRequestBody'},
    response: {$ref: 'auth#/definitions/IUserResponse'}
}


const UserRoutes: RouteOptions[] = [
    {
        url: "/register",
        method: "POST",
        schema: UserRegisterRequest,
        preHandler: [authenticateClient, ],
        handler: registerUser,
    }
]
```

Everything looks fine but when I start the application, I get the following error

```
/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:503
          cb(err)
          ^
Error: Failed building the serialization schema for POST: /user/register, due to error schema is invalid: data.properties should be object
    at /Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/src/server.ts:26:28
    at /Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastify/lib/server.js:147:31
    at manageErr (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:503:11)
    at /Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastify/fastify.js:492:11
    at Object._encapsulateThreeParam (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:551:7)
    at Boot.timeoutCall (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:447:5)
    at Boot.callWithCbOrNextTick (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:428:19)
    at release (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastq/queue.js:149:16)
    at Object.resume (/Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/fastq/queue.js:82:7)
    at /Users/meraj/codes/crowdstaffing/auth-service/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:167:18
```

If any one can point what is the issue or how to fix it, It will be of great help, stuck for quite a while. Just added question the swagger document also not loading, the ui presents but it keeps loading and loading.

Comment: I think this `"$id": "/",` is invalid. Did you try `"$id": "foobar",` instead?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I have tried different id as well like `auth` and referred as `body: {$ref: 'auth#/definitions/IUserRegisterRequestBody'},` but still get the same response

Comment: Could you add to the code the `IAllErrors` object?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I have modified my question, added more data in json schema as well modified reference, I am trying to fix it but of no use it. Let me know if you have anything i am open to try things

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon please find the complete json schema here https://justpaste.it/6c831

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon, I am debugging the node module but it crashes here `response: {$ref: 'auth#/definitions/IUserResponse'}` when i comment it it works fine